Is the default value for Windows 11's PATH variable the same as it was for Windows 10?
I'm writing documentation, and I want to be able to tell those who read it whether or not they have to set their path variable to be able to run an executable without the full path attached to the executables filename. The problem I am having is that I don't know what the default PATH variable for Windows looks like. I have configured my environment variables so many times I can't tell what paths the PATH variable held by default, and what paths were added be me.
I found this answer here
However, that answer is for Windows 10, which I assume is the same but I would like to verify that is in fact the same since people will be relying on the information I provide.

there's no need to know the default %PATH% unless it's messed up. As you can see in the other question, even in Windows 10 it changes depending on the version. You just need to prepend or append the path to the variable

I.E., there is no "standard" PATH. As software is added, PATH may change, and might even differ for the same make and model of PC, as it could be shipped with different preinstalled software.
